# Fano-like planes on $\omega$

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

We call $E\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ a *Fano-like plane* if

1. for all $x,y\in \omega$ there is $e\in E$ with $\{x,y\}\subseteq e$,
2. whenever $e_1\neq e_2\in E$ we have $|e_1\cap e_2|=1$, and
3. $|e|>1$ for all $e\in E$.

There are Fano-like planes in which not all edges (members of $E$) have the same cardinality: consider the "pseudo-pencil" for $E =\{\omega\setminus\{0\}\}\cup\big\{\{0,i\}: i \in \omega\setminus\{0\}\big\}$.

Is there a Fano-like plane $E\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ such that $|e|>2$ for all $e\in E$, and not every member of $E$ has the same cardinality?

Comment: Note that you have asked this question before both explicitly 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370950/non-pencil-infinite-projective-plane-with-edges-of-different-cardinalities

and essentially
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266511/sets-of-sets-near-pencils-and-projective-planes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Suppose $E\subseteq\mathcal P(\omega)$ is a Fano-like plane. If $e\in E$ and $x\in\omega\setminus e$, then there is a bijection between the edges containing $x$ and the points in $e$. Therefore, given two edges $e_1,e_2$ and a point $x\notin e_1\cup e_2$, there is a bijection between the points of $e_1$ and the points of $e_2$. Therefore, if there are two edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ with different cardinalities, then we must have $e_1\cup e_2=\omega$. Now choose a point $x\in e_1\setminus e_2$ and a point $y\in e_2\setminus e_1$, and let $e_3$ be the edge containing $e_1$ and $e_2$. then $e_3=\{x,y\}$ is an edge containing only two points. In fact, it's easy to see that, if the edges don't all have the same cardinality, then there is only one edge $e$ with $|e|\gt2$.